# Template Function to manipulate memory

Tags: c++, templates, memory

I'm modifying the memory of a game, therefor i do something like this:

```
*(float*)0x89635637 = 10.0f;
```

Now i want to turn this into a template function which allows me to read and set the memory with only writing the address once, i thought of something like this:

```
template <typename Variable> Variable GetSetAddress(Variable address, Variable value = NULL)
{
    if (value != NULL)
        *(Variable*)address = value;

    return *(Variable*)address;
}
```

Now i tried calling it like this:

```
float value = GetSetAddress<float>(0x89635637, 10.0f);
```

But it gave me this error:

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'float' to 'float *'

I'm pretty inexperienced with using templates, so i'd be thankful if one of you could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do with `Variable value = NULL`? In your case `Variable` is `float` so that says `float value = NULL`. Assuming your compiler defines `NULL` as `nullptr` it cannot compile

Comment: What game? On what platform? Does that platform provide any form of guarantee that modifying specific addresses has predictable behaviour? That's generally a no-no unless you're working on highly specific hardware. Anyway, that case violates object lifetime and aliasing rules unless an instance of the stated type was really constructed there beforehand. I'm also curious what the point is of returning the same value that was passed in, but that's the least of my concerns here.

Comment: @underscore_d Its a Call of Duty Game on Xbox360 and i haven't had any issues using *(float*)address = value; until now. And i'm not returning the same value that was passed in, i'm returning the value at this point in memory, so i can use this function for setting the memory and/or only returning it's current value

Comment: Ah. Well, as mentioned, you can't just compare arbitrary types to `NULL`. You either need to use separate functions to get the pointer or set its value - which would be less wasteful - or to have the new value be something like `std::optional` so that you can detect an 'empty' state for any type. I don't think `get_or_set(optional new_value)` is a good API, though.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to compare `value` to `NULL`, as `value` in this case is a `float`. Additionally, the `address` parameter shouldn't be a `Variable`, it should be an integral type which can store a pointer value, like `std::uintptr_t`

```
template <typename T> T GetSetAddress(std::uintptr_t address, T value)
{
    *(T*)address = value;
    return *(T*)address;
}
```

It's generally best to avoid c-style casts as well. You could use a `reinterpret_cast` instead, and simplify the return statement:

```
template <typename T> T GetSetAddress(std::uintptr_t address, T value)
{
    *reinterpret_cast<T*>(address) = value;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is what i needed, but you got something wrong, i only want to set the address' memory when there is a value defined and the function should return the value of the address not the value parameter.